# Synchronizing static variables

Tags: java, multithreading

What I understand by synchronizing static object which is a variable, if one thread is accessing it, other thread can't.

```
    class T3
    {
    static Integer i = 0;
    
    static void callStatic()
    {
        synchronized(T3.class)
        {
            System.out.println(i++);
            while(true);
        }
    }
    
    public void notStatic()
    {
        System.out.println(i++);
        while(true);
    }
    }

    class T2 implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("calling nonstatic");
        new T3().notStatic();
    }
}

class T implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("calling static");
        T3.callStatic();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Thread(new T()).start();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }
        new Thread(new T2()).start();
    }
}
```

But this demo program has output as :

> calling static
>
> 0
>
> calling nonstatic
>
> 1

Is my understanding wrong? Or am I missing something?

I tried, synchronzing `callStatic` method, and synchronizing `T3.class` class object too. But none worked as I thought.

**Note** : I thought, 1 will not be printed as callStatic has lock on variable i and is in infinite loop.

Comment: Pleas take the time to format your code with consistent indentation and such when asking for help.

Comment: Your edit changing `synchronized(i)` to `synchronized(T3.class)` **markedly** changes the question. Markedly changing the question such  that it invalidates the answers is not cool. If you want to ask the question of what happens with `synchronized(T3.class)`, that's fine, but do it separately. Your previous question has answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This answer relates to the original question, which had `synchronized(i)`, not `synchronized(T3.class)`, in `callStatic`. The edit really changes the question.

---

`synchronize` acts on the object, not the variable/member holding it. There are a couple of important things going on in your code.

- `synchronize(i)` does indeed synchronize access to `i` *provided* that the other code trying to use it also synchronizes. It has no effect on code that doesn't synchronize. Suppose Thread A does `synchronize(i)` and holds it (your infinite loop); then Thread B does `System.out.println(i);` Thread B can happily read `i`, there's nothing stopping it. Thread B would have to do

  ```
  synchronize (i) {
      System.out.println(i);
  }
  ```

  ...in order to be affected by Thread A's `synchronize(i)`. Your code is (attempting to) synchronized mutation, but not access.
- `i++;` with an `Integer` is effectively equivalent to `i = new Integer(i.intValue() + 1)`, because `Integer` is immutable. So it creates a *different* `Integer` object and stores that in the `i` member. So anything synchronizing on the *old* `Integer` object has no effect on code synchronizing on the *new* one. So even if your code were synchronizing both access and mutation, it wouldn't matter, because the synch would be on the old object.

  This means that the code in your `callStatic` is synchronizing on an instance of `Integer` and then repeated creating a bunch of other instances, which it is not synchronizing on.

Comment: what if I replace Integer by a mutable class?

Comment: @Batty: Then your `callStatic` would keep a lock on it (as long as you don't assign a new instance to `i`), and any code trying to synchronize on that same object would wait until the lock was released. Code *not* synchronizing on that object would not wait.

Comment: +1: Thanks for explaining that `Integer i = 0; i++` actually creates a new object. I've made this mistake before as well.

Comment: your comment explains pretty much.

Comment: `I tried, synchronzing callStatic method, and synchronizing T3.class class object too. But none worked as I thought.` I had wrtitten this in question before too, but I think it got missed. But in case of T3.class and Mutable object, same thing is happening. I guess `Code not synchronizing on that object would not wait` explains that part too.

Comment: @Batty: Yeah, definitely. There are two major things at work here: Synchronizing on an object (not a variable or data member holding it), and the fact that it only happens when both sides do it. So code synchronizing on `T3.class` will cooperate with code synchronizing on `T3.class` but not code synchronizing on anything else. Code that doesn't synchronize, doesn't synchronize.

Answer (score 3):

You don't synchronize on variables, you synchronize on objects.

`callStatic` synchronizes on `1` and then sets `i` to `2`. If `notStatic` were to enter a `synchronized(i)` block at this point, it would synchronize on `2`. No other thread has locked `2`, so it proceeds.

(Actually, `1` and `2` aren't objects, but `Integer.valueOf(1)` and `Integer.valueOf(2)` return objects, and the compiler automatically inserts the `Integer.valueOf` calls to convert `int`s to `Integer`s)

In your code, `notStatic` doesn't actually synchronize at all. It's true that only one thread can be in a `synchronized` block for a particular object at a particular time, but that has no effect on other threads that are not trying to enter a `synchronized` block.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronized blocks on static and non static don't block each other. You need to understand how `synchronized` works for this. Synchronized is done always on an object never on a variable. When you synchronize, thread takes a lock on the object's monitor, the object which you put in the `synchronized` statement braces.

Synchronized blocks on static references (like in your code) lock on the .class object of your class and not on any instance of that class. So static and non-static synchronized blocks don't block each other.

Now in your code the `notStatic` method doesn't synchronize on anything where as the `callStatic` synchronizes on the static `i` Integer object. So they don't block each other.

Comment: *"Synchronized blocks on static and non static don't block each other."* That's irrelevant here. The OP isn't using `synchronized` on methods, he/she is using it on a specific object. *"Synchronized blocks on static references (like in ur code) lock on the .class object of your class"* No, the OP's code is not synchronizing on the class, it's synchronizing on `i`.

Comment: thats very relevant here. Th OP mis-understand how synchronized blocks on statics work.

Comment: Nazgul: Look at the code again. The OP is synchronizing on a specific object. The distinction you're discussing relates to `synchronized` on methods, not in code where you give it a specific object to sync on.

Comment: Oh yes. It was actually synchronize(i) when i wrote the answer. Now it seems to have changed. Anyway the stuff between synch blocks on statics and non statics is often confused by beginners. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Nazgul: Actually, my comments were based on the `synchronized(i)`. Again, that synchronizing on `i`, not on the class. But wow, that edit by the OP is totally bogus; completely changes the question! :-|

Comment: Yes its true. But I is a static Integer wrapper. I was answering specific to synchronizing on the class inside which my code is. I was answering about using a generic static reference in synch block.

Comment: *"I was answering about using a generic static reference in synch block."* Well, as there wasn't one in the code (old or new), that's what I meant about it being irrelevant. :-)

Comment: ha ha. really true. Missed on may part. Thanks TJ.

Comment: Nazgul: (OT) Nice to talk with someone who actually listens rather than just reacting. Rare quality, nice one.